# Set video as canvas background in paint activity

Tags: android, video, canvas, draw, paint

I need to put a video as the background of my canvas. And when I pause it, to be able to paint on that frame. Is this possible?

I was thinking first of playing a video, and attaching a pause and capture button. If i pause, and then press capture, this would create a bitmap with that screencapture, i would be able to draw on it, and save it, and after that, if i go back, i would go back to the video, at the time i paused. But if it's possible, i would like to do it more dinamically, like a said, put the background of the canvas as a video, and simply pause it and draw on it, whenever i want, without changing the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put myView that i would inflate with the PaintActivity and a videoview, in the same relative layout. I bring the paint activity to the front, and put a transparent background. I set my video on the videoview, on the back.